# When ng-show / ng-if are inside an ng-repeat on an md-option, it doesnt update the variables

Tags: angularjs

```
div class="list-group" ng-repeat="(key, ListPieces) in Pieces | groupBy: 'name'">
 <div class="list-group-item">
  <div class="list-group-item-text" ng-repeat="Piece in ListPieces">
    <md-select ng-model="Piece.SelectedPiece" placeholder="@Resources.Global.SelectRef" ng-required="Piece.IsSelected" md-on-open="TooglePiece(Piece.DropDownOpen, $index)" md-on-close="TooglePiece(Piece.DropDownOpen, $index)">
        <md-option md-option-empty ng-value="{{null}}">
            @Resources.Global.RemoveCondition
        </md-option>
        <md-option ng-repeat="opt in Piece.tblRefs" ng-value="opt">
            <span ng-show="Piece.DropDownOpen === false">{{opt.Reference}}</span>
            <span ng-show="Piece.DropDownOpen === true">{{opt.Description}}</span>
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And my js:

```
$scope.TooglePiece = function (Piece, i) {
        $scope.Pieces[i].DropDownOpen = !Piece;
    };
```

So, I've this select, that I want to show just a number, the piece number, and when I open the select it will show all options, but the text of it will be more detailed it will say the Description (piece number + piece name + piece price basically) and after I chose the select options it will show only the number of that selected one.

What it happens now is that the default value is ok, I open and it appears all ok but after I choose it doesnt update the value to just the number and it will appear still the Description instead of the Reference.

How can I solve this? Any idea?

PS: I'm using AngularJS v1.6.10

Comment: You could do only `$scope.TooglePiece = function (Piece, i) {
        Piece = !Piece;
    };`

Comment: Thks for the tip. ;)
Lets hope someone knows what Im missing here.

Comment: What does `md-on-open` and `md-on-close` do? Is it firing two times when you toggle a row? Maybe you should use  `md-on-close="Piece.DropDownOpen = false"` and `md-on-open="Piece.DropDownOpen = true"`.

Comment: Btw, @SjoerddeWit putting as you said doesnt work at all, and make it worse. Because DropDownOpen is an boolean element of the Pieces object, and I need it to change that value.

Comment: md-on-open fires when I open the dropdown and md-on-close fires when the dropdown closes.

Comment: This: md-on-close="Piece.DropDownOpen = false" was my first attempt, but it wasnt working, so I decided to create an function instead. But same result.